# proper component for show location

Tags: oracle, user-interface, oracleforms

I have problem with my GUI that I want to share with you. I have a list item(type: Poplist) to show my directory details.
[image]

directory details are like:

- SRC\CLIENT1\TEST
- SRC\CLIENT2\TEST
- DEV\CLIENT3\TEST
- DEV\CLIENT4\TEST
- DEV\CLIENT5\TEST

My problem is I want to replace this GUI structure with something because length of path keep increasing and I cannot show them properly but I can not decide what component is better to use.

I tried to change my list item type to Tlist but it was not that thing I was looking for.
problem of type combobox was also developer could able to modify the location.

in your point of view tree view could be good things to replace? but what should I do with Space problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are after but you can always programmatically set the tooltip of the item. The tooltip will then be displayed when the user is hovering the mouse over the item. The drawback is that Forms don't have instance level tooltip meaning that you need to reset the tooltip on something like When-New-Record-Instance. An alternative should be to in similar way use the hint text property. A third alternative could be to open the item Editor when the user double clicks the item or something like that.

Comment: DJPeter: Hi dude, I am familiar with tooltip but I didnt know I can set it dynamically in oracle form, can you confirm that I can set it dynamically?

Comment: Yes you can set the tooltip programatically using Set_Item_Property. The syntax is 'SET_ITEM_PROPERTY('<block_name>.<item_name>', TOOLTIP_TEXT, '<value_for_tool_tip>');'.

Comment: Thanks @DJPeter, as you suggested it is working but unfortunately oracle form assign tooltip to all the rows. it means that all the rows show same value. :( Anyway thanks again.